# Why does a PendingIntent trigger onCreate even though FLAG_NO_CREATE is set

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

One of my Activities starts an `AsyncTask` and adds an ongoing notification to the notification area. This notification receives updates from within the `AsyncTask`.

I did this so the users are able to leave the Activity with the Home button and still receive progress updates during a long running operation.

Clicking the notification should return the user to this activity. The problem is that no matter what, it seems that the old activity is never used again, but instanciated new (while the `AsyncTask` still runs). The `onCreate` method of this activity gets called every time the notification gets clicked.

I tried using the `FLAG_NO_CREATE` and `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` options, but it doesn't make any difference.

What is the correct way to handle this situation? I'm developing for API level 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did this so the users are able to
>   leave the Activity with the Home
>   button and still receive progress
>   updates during a long running
>   operation.

Sounds like you should use a service.

> The problem is that no matter what, it
>   seems that the old activity is never
>   used again, but instanciated new

Yes. Android probably killed your activty. You have ABSOLUTELY NO guarantee what happens to your activity after its onStop is called.

> I'm developing for API level 4

Any particular reason you're writing for 4? That's pretty old and most phones are on 2.0 now.

Comment: The Android Docs clearly state that with the flag `FLAG_NO_CREATE` set, there won't ever be created a new activity. But that's what happens, so that doesn't really answer the myth here ;-)

Comment: You're reading it wrong. That flag isn't for starting activities. `Flag for use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int, Intent, int): if the described PendingIntent does not already exist, then simply return null instead of creating it. `