# Android notification error camera not accessible

Tags: android, android-camera

In a torch app with a notification bar, when you minimize the app with the torch turned on, if you try to click the notifications says that the camera is not accessible.

The code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Acceder a la cámara.
    if (!initTorch()) {
        return;
    }

    // Encender el flash.
    torch.on();

    // Cargar interfaz gráfica.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_on_off);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Adquirir el wake lock.
    PowerManager powerManager =
            (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, WAKE_LOCK_TAG);
    wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
    if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    // Iniciar el NotifactionManager.
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Creamos la notificación.
    createNotification();
}

private boolean initTorch() {
    try {
        // Acceder a la cámara.
        torch = new Torch();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Mostrar mensaje de error al usuario.
        Toast.makeText(this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.text_error),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Salir de la aplicación.
        finish();

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void createNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_text))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should release your resources(ie camera) using onPause() method and open it using onResume() method.

Comment: This happened to me using an AVD without camera... Check this

Answer (score 0):

Only one application can obtain the camera at a time. It's likely that your intent is creating a new task, and as a result, a new instance of your activity. Since your previous instance hasn't released the camera (from your code I can only deduce as much, as it appears that the camera is only obtained through `torch.on()` and never released), the second instance fails to obtain it.

In short, you should either:

- Adapt your intent to resume the previous activity instance, or
- Release the camera when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `onCreate()` will be called from the notification (see e.g. *[Why does a PendingIntent trigger onCreate even though FLAG_NO_CREATE is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683619/why-does-a-pendingintent-trigger-oncreate-even-though-flag-no-create-is-set)*), and you should not try to create a **`new Torch()`** if your old `Activity` is still alive.

You can try to set `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for your activity, but this does not always work (see *[Pending intent always make new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104110/pending-intent-always-make-new-activity)*). If that is the case, you should develop a more sophisticated mechanism, e.g. notification may request the old activity to release camera, and only after that it will launch the new activity.

I am afraid that such workaround will result in visible flicker of the torch, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your app's one instance is already using camera in the background. That's why you can't access it until it releases camera. Just release camera resource in on pause. And get it in on resume method. It will work.